# JPA - One to many - duplicate key value error

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I need implement join table for users which will have 2 columns `USER_CONTACTS(user_id, contact_id)`

I need store for contacts lists for users. I need to make possible that user with id 1 can have in contacts user with id 5, but user 5 can also have in contacts user with id 1 (but he musn't).

I need to be possible do following inserts:

```
INSERT INTO USERS_CONTACTS(user_id, contact_id) VALUES(1, 5);
INSERT INTO USERS_CONTACTS(user_id, contact_id) VALUES(5, 1);
```

Now I got this error:

> Unsuccessful: INSERT INTO USERS_CONTACTS(user_id, contact_id)
>   VALUES(2, 3) 2017-12-05 15:00:15.146 ERROR 14268 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: duplicate key value
>   violates unique constraint "uk_j9ggomsdbjte1eqfo5e61vh8a"

Here is my relationship implementation of User in JPA:

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "serial")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "USERS_CONTACTS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_ID"))
    private List<User> contacts;

   // ...
}
```

Can you tell me how to fix it? I am using Postgre 9.5. Thanks.

**EDIT**

For hibernate I have these properties:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: what do the logs show when org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl is generating the schema.. what constraints for that table?

Comment: which method are you calling to save the data?

Comment: I know it's pretty late but were you able to solve this ? Currently, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to solve this task yourself.

1. Enable Hibernate SQL log
2. Create a database schema with Hibernate on a test database (a tablespace) or using H2 database. You can download this project and play with mappings using unit tests: https://github.com/v-ladynev/hibernate-experimental.
3. Check generated SQL.

Perhaps, you will notice that `contact_id` is made unique by `uk_j9ggomsdbjte1eqfo5e61vh8a` constraint. The reason is that for `@OneToMany` relation child must has only one parent.

I think you need `@ManyToMany` relation.

Comment: Check my update please ... I added app properties. So I'm going to try @ManyToMany and I'll give you response.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `uk_j9ggomsdbjte1eqfo5e61vh8a` is a leftover from previous  version.

If it were so then just drop the constraint:

```
alter table USERS_CONTACTS drop constraint uk_j9ggomsdbjte1eqfo5e61vh8a;
```

Comment: Check my update please ... I have ddl in hibernate set to create-drop so I think constraints are deleted automatically.

Comment: uk_j9ggomsdbjte1eqfo5e61vh8a is actually an index created by jpa at the time of schema creation.

Answer (score -1):

There must not be an unique index on that table! Remove that index and it should work.

Comment: I have following property, check my updated question please:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop